# What is the output when you use shallow binding?

Tags: oop, paradigms, dynamic-scope

```
x : integer := 3                //global scope
y : integer := 4                //global scope
procedure add
    x := x + y
procedure second(P : procedure)
    x : integer := 5
    P()
procedure first
    y : integer := 6
    second(add)
first()               //first procedure call in the main function
write integer(x)      //function to print the value of a variable
```

After first() is run, add() modifies second::x, not ::x right? So the output is 3...
but the answer given is: Dynamic Scope (shallow binding): (x=5+y=6)=11

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The semantics of your fictitious language is somewhat vague and I am forced to make assumptions, for instance a statement such as ...

```
    x : integer := 5
```

... in function `second` is defining a new local variable `x` initialized to 5 rather than assigning a new value to global variable `x`.

Then with *shallow binding* by time `add` is called function `second` will have set local variable `x` to 5 and function `first` will have set local variable `y` to 6. Therefore `add` will compute a new value of `x` as 11. This I think we all agree on.

But I would interpret function `add` as updating the *local variable `x` of function `second`*, not the global `x` variable, leaving the global variable `x` unmodified. Therefore 3 should be printed.